# change table name dynamically using a macro generate_alias_name in DBT

Tags: dbt

I have table name as rw_ghi_abc.
I want to remove rw_ from the table name and for this I am using macro generate_alias_name as :

```
{% macro generate_alias_name(re,custom_alias_name=none, node=none) -%}
    {%- if custom_alias_name is none -%}
        {{ re.search('g\w+',node.name) }}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ custom_alias_name | trim }}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I am using re.search so that I can skip rw_ from the name, after dbt run it gives an error as:

```
Database Error in model rw_ghi_abc(models/RAW/abc/rw_ghi_abc.sql)
  001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
  syntax error line 1 at position 77 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 102 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 113 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 131 unexpected ''RAW''.
  syntax error line 1 at position 140 unexpected ''abc''.
  syntax error line 1 at position 152 unexpected ''rw_ghi_abc''.
  syntax error line 1 at position 184 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 234 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 631 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 672 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 698 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 771 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 831 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 884 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 920 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 953 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 984 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 1,017 unexpected '='.
  syntax error line 1 at position 1,085 unexpected ','.
  compiled Code at target/run/data/models/RAW/abc/rw_ghi_abc.sql
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the compiled SQL and take it from there

Comment: Can you post the raw and compiled code for `rw_ghi_abc.sql` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the model name always starts with 'rw_', you can use something like this:

```
{% macro generate_alias_name(custom_alias_name=none, node=none) -%}

    {%- if custom_alias_name is none -%}
        {%- if node.name.startswith('rw_') -%}
            {{ node.name[node.name.find('rw_') + 3 : node.name|length] }}
        {%- else -%}
            {{ node.name }}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ custom_alias_name | trim }}
    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```